# Convert a column to a list of prevoius columns in a Dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I would like to create a column that is the form of a list of values from two previous columns, such as location that is made up of the long and lat columns.

[This is what the DataFrame looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0fqSK.png)

Comment: Can you give a sample of expected output?

Comment: What is your desired form of output?

Comment: A new column in the form of a list. A example cell could be -1447104, 55.008766

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new columne based on other columns using `zip`, as follows:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'admin_port': ['NORTH SHIELDS', 'OBAN'],
    'longitude': [-1.447104, -5.473469],
    'latitude': [55.008766, 54.415695],
})

df['new'] = pd.Series(list(zip(df['longitude'].values, df['latitude'].values)))

print(df)
```

```py
>>> df
      admin_port  longitude   latitude                     new
0  NORTH SHIELDS  -1.447104  55.008766  (-1.447104, 55.008766)
1           OBAN  -5.473469  54.415695  (-5.473469, 54.415695)
```

For your information, you can see how to use `zip()` here: https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_zip.asp